# Set-UnifiedGroup is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

i have a written a code to connect to the Exchange server, and then set unified group welcome message to false. But for some reason my session does not seem to work.

```
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Trying to establish a session with exchange"
try
{
    $ProxyOptions = New-PSSessionOption -ProxyAccessType IEConfig
    $session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $credentials -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection -SessionOption $ProxyOptions
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Succesfully established a session"

    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Trying to set Welcome Message to false"

    try
    {
        Import-PSSession $session -DisableNameChecking
        Set-UnifiedGroup $groupAlias -UnifiedGroupWelcomeMessageEnabled:$false
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Succesfully disabled the welcoming message"
    }
    catch
    {
        $errorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Error occured..."
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor blue $errorMessage
    }
}
catch
{
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Error while establishing a session"
    $errorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Blue $errorMessage
}
```

i get an error

> The term "Set-UnifiedGroup" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Does your account have rights to run that cmdlet? [Here's how to check it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-server/find-exchange-cmdlet-permissions?view=exchange-ps)

Answer (score 3):

My account didn't have the Exchange Administrator role as we have implemented Azure AD Privileged Identity Management in our organization. I was able to load the module, login and e.g. use `Get-UnifiedGroup`, but `Set-UnifiedGroup` was missing.

After activating the Exchange Administrator role and reloading the PowerShell-Module, the CMDlet was available.

Answer (score 1):

It's required to have the Exchange Online Management Tools installed.

Please see the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps#install-the-exo-v2-module) for details on installing the Exchange Online PowerShell module.

In Summary, install the module using:

```
Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement
```

Details on how to authenticate can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps)

Because I'm using PowerShell v7, I used the following to authenticate:

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName navin@contoso.onmicrosoft.com
```

This answer is to update the answer @vonPryz provided since it's much easier now to install the management tools than the method they offered.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by missing the Exchange Management module. It either is not loaded or not installed at all.

A [detailed MS article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/samdrey/2017/12/17/how-to-load-exchange-management-shell-into-powershell-ise-2/) describes how to work with the management tools on remote workstation. In case of link rot, here are some of the relevant parts:

Install [Exchange Management Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/plan-and-deploy/post-installation-tasks/install-management-tools?view=exchserver-2019), if not already done.

Run a script that loads the tools and connects into Exchange:

```
$CallEMS = ". '$env:ExchangeInstallPath\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'; Connect-ExchangeServer -auto -ClientApplication:ManagementShell "
Invoke-Expression $CallEMS
```

FWIW, the script is using `Invoke-Expression`, which is often [not a great idea](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/). Likely,

```
. $env:ExchangeInstallPath\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1
Connect-ExchangeServer -auto -ClientApplication:ManagementShell
```

would work as well.